# How to add items to a list properly

Tags: python, list, class, typeerror, abstract-class

I am currently learning python. I am learning about classes, inheritance, and abstract classes. Here is the constructor in question:

```
def __init__(self, sourceCollection = None):
    """Sets the initial state of self, which includes the
    contents of sourceCollection, if it's present."""
    self.size = 0
    if sourceCollection:
        for item in sourceCollection:
            self.add(item)
```

I am getting the following error, and I don't know why:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

In case is helps, here is my add method:

```
def add(self, item):
    """Adds item to self."""
    # Check array memory here and increase it if necessary
    
    self.items[len(self)] = item
    self.size += 1
```

Could anyone assist me with why I am getting this error? I did some research, but to no avail. Thanks so much in advance!!!

Comment: Please **always** provide a [mcve]. That means we can copy and paste it and get the same exact errors. If you are getting an error message, **always** post the full error message, including the stack trace

Comment: don't use `self.size` to keep track of the size of the list, the list knows better, use `len(self.items)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` has a method to add all elements from an iterable

Don't use `self.size` to keep track of the number of elements in `self.items`, use `len(self.items)`

```
def __init__(self, sourceCollection = None):
    """Make a copy of sourceCollection"""
    self.items = []
    if not sourceCollection: return
    self.items.extend(sourceCollection)

def add(self, item):
    """Adds item to self."""
    self.items.append(item)

@property
def size(self):
    return len(self.items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do (`.append()`):

```
def add(self, item):
    """Adds item to self."""
    # Check array memory here and increase it if necessary
    
    self.items.append(item)
    self.size += 1
```